# How to make a MessageBox wait in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a loading screen with messageboxes, but you have to click the OK button... which I don't think anyone likes.
I want to make a program that will open the messagebox then wait for about 1 or 2 seconds, then open the next one and keep doing it until the loading is complete, here's the code I have so far.

```
Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Loading.", "Loading Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        If result = DialogResult.OK Then
            MessageBox.Show("Loading..", "Loading Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If result = DialogResult.OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("Loading...", "Loading Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Loading Complete.", "Loading Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: there isnt anything happening between MessageBox calls, so why?  To answer your question, NO - they are meant to stop everything and get input from the user.  Try using a splashscreen instead

Comment: You could create a custom dialog, then have a timer tick down until you want it to close.

Comment: You could programatically click ok with a timer tick but thats hacky, I'd second Plutonix's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the message box is just a way of letting users know where the process is, it's best to just give them a progress bar or update a label on the form with your message.  In addition, turn on the hour glass so users know that the program is still executing.